# How does one set the background colour of individual cells rather than of events?

Tags: fullcalendar

Rather than create events for Christmas and Easter and the like, I'd like to be able colour the date cells affected, and even perhaps have a grey translucent text for each event. Is there any easy way to do this in FullCalendar?

**EDIT**

It's been pointed out to me that fc-state-highlight is used to highlight fc-today, so perhaps a similar thing could be done, applying a css class to cells and defining it as "public holiday colour". A thought. The problem is how does one apply this class to the relevant dates such that it works within FC without breaking anything.

Comment: What version of fce are you using?

Comment: Also what view are you looking to do this in?

Comment: version: FC 2.0.1. view: month, agendaDay, agendaWeek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done using [eventAfterAllRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/). Make a separate ajax call to find all of the holidays then change the color of the td. Example for month and holiday being June 1st, done with FC 2.0.1: http://jsfiddle.net/marcrazyness/C8jpm

```
       eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
            //Use view.intervalStart and view.intervalEnd to find date range of holidays
            //Make ajax call to find holidays in range.
            var fourthOfJuly = moment('2014-07-04','YYYY-MM-DD');
            var holidays = [fourthOfJuly];
            var holidayMoment;
            for(var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {              
                holidayMoment = holidays[i];
                if (view.name == 'month') {
                    $("td[data-date=" + holidayMoment.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "]").addClass('holiday');
                } else if (view.name =='agendaWeek') {
                    var classNames = $("th:contains(' " + holidayMoment.format('M/D') + "')").attr("class");
                    if (classNames != null) {
                        var classNamesArray = classNames.split(" ");
                        for(var i = 0; i < classNamesArray.length; i++) {
                            if(classNamesArray[i].indexOf('fc-col') > -1) {
                                $("td." + classNamesArray[i]).addClass('holiday');
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (view.name == 'agendaDay') {
                    if(holidayMoment.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
                        $("td.fc-col0").addClass('holiday');
                    };
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

when doc ready, have a js function to select all TDs, with data-date the ones you want, and add CSS class to them. I don't know if it works, just an idea.

Comment: Yes, that's where my mind was going too. A bit messy. Looks like, at least for the interim, that one has to create non-modifiable events for public holidays and the like.