# Fullcalendar 2.0.2 change cells background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, annotations, fullcalendar

I am currently searching a solution to change cells background in fullcalendar depends on availability or holidays for example.

I found several solutions:
- elhigu/fullcalendar on github (+)
- lcrodriguez/fullcalendar  on github (+)
But they are for older versions of fullcalendar.

I also found this solution, :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24375088/3641008

I would like to know if someone have another solution or plugin for 2.0.2 version.
I tried using the file found at the end here : https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=144.. but no success..

I am pretty new to librairy or plungin use. 
Thanks for your help.

(+) Sorry I cannot post more than 2 links

**EDIT**

I finally got fullcalendar annotations ([link](https://github.com/elhigu/fullcalendar/blob/master/demos/annotations.html)) working with fullcalendar 1.6.4.
But I really need that fullcalendar2.0.2 (or higher) works.

Comment: Here are the two links :  
https://github.com/elhigu/fullcalendar  ||    
https://github.com/lcrodriguez/fullcalendar

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did on mine:

I set the `eventRender`

```
eventRender: function (event, element, icon) {

    if (isHoliday) {//do your own validation                        
        element.find('.fc-event-title').append("<span class='ultra-light'> is a holiday</span>");
    }
},
```

Of course once you find the `element.find('.fc-event-title')` you can append css or do whatever else you want to do it.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to color table cells, not render the "holiday period" as an event. I would like to render like the annotations solution (https://github.com/elhigu/fullcalendar), but this solution is for FullCalendar v1.5.4